# Stacked bar plot from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a dataframe like this

```
     val     others
0    200     34
1    500     n
2    300     45
```

I would like to plot directly from df producing a horizontal stacked bar plot.

I tried several things like

```
df.plot(y='val', kind='barh', stacked=True)
```

but output is always a figure with that many plots as I have rows...

Comment: Base on the sample data ... you can not .

Comment: Why not? If I try to do `plt.plot(x=0, y=df.val, stacked=True)` it doesn't work either

Comment: Can you, based on the data you have, describe precisely how your barplot is to look like? Else, it's really hard to understand the desired outcome. (Also, what is `n`?)